# data-bind returns function instead of text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I´m using twitter bootstrap v3.0 and knockout.js v2.3.0.

When i click the addAnswer button and read the value from answerOption1  it returns a method like this:

```
function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.equalityComparer&&c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0])||(c.K(),d=arguments[0],c.J()),this;a.q.bb(c);return d}
```

instead of the actual text avlue: "i am an answer text".

**Source:**

```
    function Question(data) {
    this.title = data.title;
    this.question = data.question;
}

function Answer(data) {
    this.type = data.type;
    this.inputText = ko.observable(data.inputText);
    this.correctAnswer = ko.observable(data.correctAnswer);
    this.explanation = ko.observable(data.explanation);
    this.isCorrect = ko.observable(data.isCorrect);
}

var AnswerType = {
    MULTI_CHOICE : "multichoice",
    YES_NO : "yesno",
    INPUT_TEXT : "inputtext"        
}

function QuestionViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable("my title");
    self.question = ko.observable("my question");

    self.currentAnswerType = AnswerType.MULTI_CHOICE;
    self.currentAnswer = ko.observable("add new answer..");
    self.currentExplanation = ko.observable("");
    self.isCorrect = ko.observable("");


    /* Answers operations */
    self.multipleAnswers = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addAnswer = function(){
        if(self.currentAnswerType == AnswerType.MULTI_CHOICE){
            self.multipleAnswers.push(new Answer({type : this.currentAnswerType, inputText: this.currentAnswer, correctAnswer : '', explanation: this.currentExplanation, isCorrect: this.isCorrect}));
        }else if(self.currentAnswerType == AnswerType.YES_NO){

        }else{

        }
    }

    /* Question operations */
    self.questions = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addQuestion = function() {
        self.questions.push(new Question({
            title : this.title(),
            question : this.question()
        }))
    }
}


<div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="answerOption1">Add
                                new answer</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answerOption1" data-bind="value: currentAnswer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                data-bind="click: addAnswer">Add</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1 text-center">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="answerOption1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1 text-center">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: you need to do this.currentAnswer() or this.currentAnswer.toJs()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

observables are functions, when you are using them in the javascript code you need to have the () on them to get their return values.

```
self.multipleAnswers.push(new Answer({type : this.currentAnswerType, inputText: this.currentAnswer, correctAnswer : '', explanation: this.currentExplanation, isCorrect: this.isCorrect}));
```

should be

```
self.multipleAnswers.push(new Answer({type : this.currentAnswerType, inputText: this.currentAnswer(), correctAnswer : '', explanation: this.currentExplanation(), isCorrect: this.isCorrect()}));
```